# Помогите написать программу пожалуйста

Tags: bash

Организовать ввод и вывод одной целой, двух вещественных и трех символьных переменных

Comment: @Габи на данном форуме не принято выполнять работу за кого-либо. Пожалуйста укажите, что вы сделали сами, и что не получилось

Comment: за вами выехали

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ох щас минусов нахватаю (

```
#! /bin/bash

var1 = var2 = var4 = var4 = var5 = var6 = 0 
echo var1
echo var2
echo var3
echo var4
echo var5
echo var6
```

Comment: скорее плюсов за юмор :)

Answer (score 0):

Что немаловажно для начала определиться с языком программирования. Я приведу вам код на Pascal.

```
// Объявляем переменные
var 
  int_a: integer;
  float_a, float_b, float_c: double;
  char_a, char_b, char_c: char;
begin
  // одна целая переменная
  readln(int_a);
  writeln(int_a);
  // две вещественные переменные
  readln(float_a);
  writeln(float_a);
  readln(float_b);
  writeln(float_b);
  // три символа
  read(char_a);
  write(char_a);
  read(char_b);
  write(char_b);
  read(char_c);
  write(char_c);
end.
```

[Немного больше можно прочитать на сайте в ссылке](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/book/view.php?id=524&chapterid=219)

нет ничего сложного главное для себя понять чего хотите. А по сути непонятен ваш прогресс, что у вас вызвало затруднения. :)

Comment: @DreamChild это из-за того что ответил?

Comment: Нет, я не настолько плохой, чтобы ставить минусы только за сам факт ответа) Я его поставил за то, что у вас нет никакого намека на типизацию, а в этом весь смысл вопроса (признаки венгерской нотации не в счет). Судя по всему ТС совсем-совсем не знаком с программированием, а потому ваш ответ для него - темный лес. Более того, в вопросе вообще не указан язык программирования, а вы почему-то используете паскаль

Comment: Согласен, что отсутствие типизации у меня - это явный пробел. При наличии причины в комментариях, я бы сразу понял свой промах, и поправил бы ответ (или удалил бы его, если как такового смысла в ответе нет). 

*Кстати по данным критериям подходит и другой ответ: нет типизации, выбран конкретный язык, темный лес (мало того, как такого ввода данных там нет).*, так что для меня Ваши причины до сих пор загадочны :)

Comment: @IVsevolod первый ответ я не минуснул потому что это язык, которого я просто-напросто не знаю (я тоже подумал, что там нет типизации, однако действовать по принципу "Пастернака не читал, но осуждаю" не стал). Более того, из пояснений автора я подумал, что это какой-то прикол

Comment: @DreamChild хорошо, теперь понял Ваше мнение :)